# getDrawable from resource is not the same size as bitmap

Tags: android, drawable

I load drawable from resource image png like this:
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somepng);
Png file on disk  has a size of 102x59 but received drawable has already 204x118.
Why?

Comment: Can depends of your screen resolution density: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html look like you provide a `mdpi` image and test on `xdpi` device.

Answer (score 0):

Can depends of your screen resolution density: [take a look at this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) look like you provide a mdpi image and test on xdpi device.